# Advice on GUI timer to display background thread's elapsed time?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread, qtimer

**Issue**

I have a PyQt GUI where the user presses a button to start a background thread (`workerThread`, which is subclassed from `QThread`). I would like to have a timer display (in the form of a `QLabel`) to show how much time has elapsed since `workerThread` started, and I would like this timer to stop as soon as the `workerThread` exits.

**Possible solution**

I've thought about creating another independent thread (`timerThread`) that uses a `QTimer` to send a signal to a slot to update the `QLabel` in the main GUI thread with the elapsed time every 1 second. This `timerThread` will exit as soon as it receives a terminate signal from `workerThread`.

However, I'd have to start `timerThread` at the same time as `WorkerThread`, and I'm not sure how to this.

**Question**

Is there an easier way to do this? Is `QTimer` even the right approach to start with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this. In this example, `myThread` starts the `timerThread` as a child process when it's `run` method is called. It's `timeElapsed` signal is connected to the `timerThread`s `timeElapsed` signal. The `timerThread` will check each second `while` the `parent` `isRunning` and emit a `timeElapsed` signal if `True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class timerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    timeElapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(timerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.timeStart = None

    def start(self, timeStart):
        self.timeStart = timeStart

        return super(timerThread, self).start()

    def run(self):
        while self.parent().isRunning():
            self.timeElapsed.emit(time.time() - self.timeStart)
            time.sleep(1)


class myThread(QtCore.QThread):
    timeElapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myThread, self).__init__(parent)

        self.timerThread = timerThread(self)
        self.timerThread.timeElapsed.connect(self.timeElapsed.emit)

    def run(self):
        self.timerThread.start(time.time())

        iterations = 3
        while iterations:
            print "Running {0}".format(self.__class__.__name__)
            iterations -= 1
            time.sleep(2)        


class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__() 

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Start Threading!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.myThread = myThread(self)
        self.myThread.timeElapsed.connect(self.on_myThread_timeElapsed)
        self.myThread.finished.connect(self.on_myThread_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.myThread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_myThread_timeElapsed(self, seconds):
        self.label.setText("Time Elapsed: {0}".format(seconds))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_myThread_finished(self):
        print "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That was brilliantly answered! Reading the code was a pleasure... it all made sense. (this is only my 3rd day working with Qt/PyQt, and I could understand exactly what your code was doing).