# Stopping timer in PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, timer, pyqt4

I have an application with 3 different windows. One of them consists:

Start Button

Stop Button

LCDNumber Display

When i press Start Button, timer starts and elapsed time is displayed on LCDNumber Display. However when i press stop the whole GUI is stuck, nothing works, no button etc. I am aware that it is because of the while loop used in this code. However I don't know how to efficiently stop working thread with while loop. Please give me some tips, maybe solution for my problem.

TimerWindow instance is created in **main**. TimerWindow constructor creates a myThread class instance as you can see. myThread class instance creates timerThread class instance. I hope it's obvious when you look at this code. If you need full code tell me in the comment and i will post it :)
My code is based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368400/advice-on-gui-timer-to-display-background-threads-elapsed-time)

Buttons are connected to the following methods:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.STARTbutton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), TimerWindow.on_button_clicked)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.STOPbutton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), TimerWindow.on_myThread_finished)
```

Here are the classes

```
class TimerWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui_timer = Ui_TimerWindow() #create instance of Ui_TimerWindow
        self.ui_timer.setupUi(self) #call setupUi which will create all the GUI elements

        self.myThread = myThread(self)
        self.myThread.timeElapsed.connect(self.on_myThread_timeElapsed)
        self.myThread.finished.connect(self.on_myThread_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.myThread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_myThread_timeElapsed(self, seconds):
        self.ui_timer.lcdNumber.display(seconds)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_myThread_finished(self):
        self.myThread.terminate()
        print "Done"
```

something

```
class myThread(QtCore.QThread):
    """this is the main thread class called when we want to create a timer"""

    timeElapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myThread, self).__init__(parent)

        self.timerThread = timerThread(self) #create an instance of timerThread class
        self.timerThread.timeElapsed.connect(self.timeElapsed.emit)

    def run(self):
        self.timerThread.start(time.time())

        iterations = 10000000000
        while iterations:
            print "Running {0}".format(self.__class__.__name__)
            iterations -= 1
            time.sleep(100)

class timerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    """instance of this class i created when myThread class object is created and myThread's class constructor is used"""
    timeElapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(timerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.timeStart = None

    def start(self, timeStart):
        self.timeStart = timeStart

        return super(timerThread, self).start()

    def run(self):
        while self.parent().isRunning():
            self.timeElapsed.emit(time.time() - self.timeStart)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You just need to add a flag attribute to `myThread` and check it inside the loop (i.e. `while self.flag and iterations:`). To stop the loop, just set the flag attribute to `False`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I changed my code so that the while loop in myThread class would print iterations all the time. Without this flag, when I press stop button the iteration number stops to be printed so the loop in fact is TERMINATED. Apparently, there is some other reason why my GUI freezes ;/